How to split a column into 2 different columns with condition
I have this data about brands and sellers.



Brand
BB_seller




Biotherm
Amazon


BVLGARI
3rd Party


BVLGARI
3rd Party


Carolina Herrera
Amazon


Chanel
Amazon


Chanel
Amazon



select Brand, substring([Buy Box Seller],1,9) as BB_seller
from italy_keepa
where [Buy Box Seller] is not null
order by Brand

I want to transform it into this type of table - so actually I just need to count different types of sellers



Brand
Amazon
3rd party




Chanel
6
10



I tried this code - but numbers in count are strange
select Brand, count(distinct([Buy Box Seller])) as BB_seller
from italy_keepa
group by Brand
order by BB_seller desc




Brand
BB_seller




Chanel
10


Tom Ford
3


Prada
3


Valentino
2




When you asked your question, you were told "Please make sure to post code (, data) and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

You need to use 'PIVOT` technique for this case. I just provide simple example of such query, and you can adopt it for you case:
select 
    ProductCategoryID,
    count(case when Color  = 'Black' then ProductID end) balack_count,
    count(case when Color  != 'Black' then ProductID end) other_count
from product
group by ProductCategoryID 

Try it online

Yes it works! Thank you

You can try using the 'PIVOT' command to achieve this. Here's the sample:
SELECT Brand, Amazon, `3rd Party` FROM italy_keepa PIVOT (
    COUNT(`Buy Box Seller`) 
    FOR `Buy Box Seller` IN ('Amazon', '3rd Party')
)

Hope this helps!
